# IdentityServer4: How to specify an identity provider as part of authorization request?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I've implemented IdentityServer4 with external providers in my project. Now when a restricted page is requested, the user is redirected to my IdentityServer login page, where he can either enter a username and password or login with Google or Facebook. How can I specify which identity provider to be used from the client side so that, my identity server will directly redirect to the particular provider without showing the login page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass custom parameter to the authorize endpoint .

If you are using the OpenID Connect Middleware , you can add the value to query string of authorize request of `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` function :

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
            {
                var headerValue = n.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-idp"];

                n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("X-idp", headerValue.ToString());

                await Task.FromResult(0);
            };
```

You could create custom CustomAuthorizeAttribute to pass the identity provider you want to login :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _idp;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string idp)
    {
        _idp = idp;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("X-idp", _idp);
    }
}
```

In your controller :

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute("AAD")]
```

So that on Identity Server side , you could get the needed Identity provide information via query string :

AccountController.cs(ASP.Net Identity):

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger, IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _logger = logger;
        _interaction = interaction;
    }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {

        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
        var idp = context.Parameters["X-idp"];

        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(ipd, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, idp);

        //var customId = HttpContext.Request.Query["X-CustomId"].ToString();
        //var queryString = HttpContext.Request.Query["returnUrl"].ToString();
        //// Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        //await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        //ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        //return View();
    }

    .....
}
```

In above code sample , it uses `IIdentityServerInteractionService` method `GetAuthorizationContextAsync` to get the value , if you have external provider like :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddOpenIdConnect("AAD", "Azure Active Directory", options =>
   {
       options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
       options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
       options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
       options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
       options.Scope.Add("openid");

   });
```

It will find that authentication schema by name `AAD` and start the Azure AD login process .